# Polymorphism Cell Writing

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am working on a project where the requirements say that you must use polymorphism to support cells of different types that print differently, but share a common way to store and display the input string that was used to set the cell. This seems extremely vague to me. It was suggested to me that I create a Cell superclass, and then create classes for the types of cells. The types of cells that I need to write are doubles, Strings, and Dates. I have the following code for the array where I am storing my cells.

```
final static int WIDTH = 7;
final static int HEIGHT = 10;
static Cell[][] sheet = new Cell[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

How am I to accomplish this if I am supposed to use subclasses for the different data types? Can someone please explain this concept to me?

Comment: Do you know what "*polymorphism*" is?  Have you seen any Java samples (possibly using Animals or Shapes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be kind of hard to write these questions to be perfectly clear, but here's the basic idea.  You need something like an abstract base class for Cell that has the common data and declares an abstract method for the things you must implement.  Then you derive a subclass for each concrete kind of cell, say Erythrocyte, Leucocyte, and Stem, and give them a concrete implementation.

Then you can, say, make an array of Cells, and call each one, depending on polymorphism to invoke the right concrete method.

**Update**

Oh, you didn't mean that kind of Cell. :-)

I don't want to show you all the code, but it's going to basically look like

```
public class Cell { private int width, height; /*... more stuff */ }
public class ACell extends Cell { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I really appreciate the help! This helped me get through my CS class last semester. I haven't been able to reply to you since school got out. Again, thanks so much for the help! I am a high school student that is still eagerly learning to code and this helped me solidify my understanding of polymorphism!